# Is it possible to programmatically reload JavaScript files in mobile browsers on page refresh?

Tags: caching, client-side, server-side

I am developing a web application and while working on a desktop, I am used to force reloading pages using `Ctrl-F5` in the browser to clear any cached copies when I make changes to javascript files.

I am not able to do that in mobile browsers since they don't have a `Ctrl-F5` or forced reload feature. I want to refrain from using version numbers in the javascript's querystrings to force a reload files whenever I make changes.

Is there any client-side or server-side way to force a mobile browser to refresh javascripts when reloading a webpage?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Once JS is loaded, its in memory so even if you remove the script tag, the content is still there unlike CSS file where you can add and remove css files.

Comment: you can change the version in querystring - which will force download a new version if the js file - however the client will have to poll for a version change

Comment: Why do you need this? Wouldn't it be better to define a custom event and fire it programmatically?

Comment: @Royi Namir i don't wanted to use querystring approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. The following method can be used to load in a JavaScript file programmatically.

```
function LoadJsFile(jsUrl) 
{
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", request);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, how does this avoid caching?

Comment: This doesn't, but if you want to do that simply add a query string parameter to your JavaScript reference and pass a random number or a data string. This will cause it to load it a fresh version of the JavaScript file. i.e http://domain.com/myfile.js?random=1234